# Does GLSurfaceView.onPause() destroy the context?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I'm using GLSurfaceView.onPause() to manage resources (i.e. stop the rendering thread to allow  a more responsive view to be presented). It appears to be require the surface to be re-created but I haven't seen this detailed in the documentation.

Can someone confirm that this is the case?

Cheers, 
Josh

Answer (score 4):

Yes that is the case.
But if you want to improve the responsiveness of another view or dialog for a limited amount of time you have some other options.

- if you target api level 11 or higher you can use [setPreserveEGLContext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setPreserveEGLContextOnPause%28boolean%29) on the GLSurfaceView
- you can use [setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setRenderMode%28int%29)
- you can set a flag and in your [onDrawFrame()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html#onDrawFrame%28javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10%29) you return early if this flag is set.

Answer (score 0):

yes it will be recreated on pause because glView extends SurfaceView and SurfaceView always recreates when activity goes on pause.